# Reference to Razor Render Script

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, render

I've opened new *MVC 4 (.net 4.0) project in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web*, and I've noticed that the `BundleConfig` is missing, so I created it, and also I've added `System.Web.Optimization`, and after that everything was working fine, except:

In the view, when I try to render Script like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

I get error, so I must declare the rendering like this:

```
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

How can I escape the whole referencing ?

Answer (score 2):

In your view, include the Optimization namespace and render the bundle:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried this, it helps, but I have another project that is build in Visual Studio 2010, and the view is clear, there isn't including the namespace into the view, simply the razor knows how to find the Rendering method, and I'm curious why  isn't  here as same as there.. so I want to achive that, if it is possible